# How to add a library path to a makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I was making a makefile for cross-compilation between a host and arm based microcontroller. So how do I add a specific library to the recipe of the makefile?

```
include sources.mk

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MSP432)
# Platform Overrides

# Architectures Specific Flags
LINKER_FILE = msp432p401r.lds
CPU = cortex-m4
ARCH = thumb
SPECS = nosys.specs
CPP = -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS) -DMSP432
# Compiler Flags and Defines

CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
endif


ifeq ($(PLATFORM),HOST)

CC = gcc
CPP= DHOST
endif


TARGET =c1m2
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map -T $(LINKER_FILE)
CFLAGS =  -Wall -Werror -g -O0 -$(CPP) -I/Desktop/ese-coursera- 
course1/assessments/m2/include/common/platform.h
-std=c99



.PHONY: build
build: all

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET).out


.PHONY: clean
clean:  
rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET).out $(TARGET).map

%.o : %.c
$(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
OBJS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

$(TARGET).out: $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Is this the right way of doing it?(all the tabs and indents for the make file has been given properly, though it is not seen in the code here)

Iam getting this as the error

```
main.c:23:10: fatal error: platform.h: No such file or directory
 #include "platform.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:67: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Also this is my source.mk file

```
SOURCES = Desktop/ese-coursera-course1/assessments/m2/src

# Add your include paths to this variable
INCLUDES = Desktop/ese-coursera-course1/assessments/m2/include/common/platform.h
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: add `LIBB = -LDesktop/ese-coursera-course1/assessments/m2/include/common/`

Comment: Your CFLAGS do not do anything with the Includes variable?

Comment: I also sincerely doubt that you have a `/Desktop` directory or a `Desktop` directory next to the makefile. Did you mean `~/Desktop` ? If possible, try to make all paths relative to the Makefile, so other can also use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to make sure all paths you give are relative to the Makefile.

I'm surprised your compiler actually does anything since your `SOURCES` variable is a directory, not a list of `.c` files. It should probably look like:

```
SOURCES = src/main.c
```

this will make `OBJS` contain `src/main.o` and the implicit rule will be able to fire.

Next, the `INCLUDES` variable should reference a **directory** using the `-I` flag, like so:

```
INCLUDES = -Iinclude/common
```

You should then use it in the `CFLAGS` definition as follows:

```
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Werror -g -O0 -$(CPP) $(INCLUDES) -std=c99
```

Other things I noticed:

- Your LDFLAGS unconditionally uses the `msp432p401r.lds` linker script, even in the HOST case. This should probably be added conditionally in the `ifeq` block like so: `LDFLAGS += -T msp432p401r.lds`. You should be careful not to overwrite LDFLAGS later with `LDFLAGS=`, so it is best if you move the definition of CFLAGS and LDFLAGS to the top of the file or always use `+=` to modify these variables.
- Following on from that: if your link step uses the linker script, you should add an explicit rule that encodes this dependency: `$(TARGET).out: $(LINKER_FILE)`.
- The `build -> all -> $(TARGET).out` dependency chain is a bit redundant. Why not make `build` directly depend on `$(TARGET).out`?